# set relative titles per row for multiple chart plot

Tags: r, plot, title

Is there any way to set 5 sub-titles for a plot consisting of 20 graphs in 4 columns and 5 rows?

Attached the picture of the graphs.

I tried inserting titles the following way, but adjusting the output plot will move the titles around.

```
mtext("Frankfurt (Forecast 2012 - 2033)", side = 3, line = -1.5, outer = TRUE)
```

I found the following few lines of codes but those seem to relate only to one of the 20 graphs, and not the entire plot

```
op <- par("usr") 
par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1)) 
text(0.5,0.5,"TEST") 
par(usr = op)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/prgHU.png

Comment: could you provide a sample data for a reproducible example ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach.

```
mat <- matrix(c(rep(1,4), 6:9, rep(2,4), 10:13, rep(3,4), 14:17, rep(4,4), 18:21, 
                rep(5,4), 22:25), ncol=4, byrow=T)
mat                  # 1-5: subtitle, 6-: mainplot
layout(mat, heights=c(rep(c(1, 20), 5)))   # heights setting (rough)

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
for(i in 1:5) {
  plot(0, 0, type="n", ann=F, axes=F)  # plotting white paper & subtitle
  mtext(side=1, line=0.2, "subtitle")  # do it five times
}

par(mar=c(2, 2, 2.7, 1), mgp=c(3, 0.6, 0))  # margins and tick lab position set
for(i in 1:20) {
  plot(rnorm(30), ann=F)            # main plot
  title(LETTERS[i], line=0.3)       # each title (don't use plot(main=))
}
```